# How to define custom properties in enumeration in Python (Javascript-like)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In JavaScript we can do this:

```
var Color = {
    YELLOW: { value: 1, displayString: "Yellow" },
    GREEN: { value: 2, displayString: "Green" },
}
```

So I can call:

```
Color.YELLOW.displayString
```

In Java we can do this:

```
public enum Color {

    YELLOW (1, "Yellow"),
    GREEN (2, "Green"),

    private Color(String value, int displayString){
        this.value = value;
        this.displayString = displayString;
    }

    private final int value;
    private final String displayString;

    public String getValue() {return value;}
    public String getDisplayString() {return displayString;}
}
```

So I can call:

```
Color.YELLOW.getDisplayString()
```

After much research I haven't found a clean way to do this in Python using the built-in Enum module. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: The javascript is an object more closely related to a HashMap in Java. There is a Dictionary in python that might serve your purposes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two concepts involved here: enumerations and attribute-style access to object members that can be initialised inline. For the latter, you'll need some kind of custom class, but since you want something very straightforward, a `namedtuple` is sufficient for that. So, combining `namedtuple` and `enum`, this could be a solution:

```
from enum import Enum
from collections import namedtuple

Color = namedtuple('Color', ['value', 'displayString'])

class Colors(Enum):

    @property
    def displayString(self):
        return self.value.displayString

    yellow = Color(1, 'Yellow')
    green = Color(2, 'Green')

print(Colors.yellow.displayString)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is what I needed! Combined with the use of @property annotations we can access underlying values directly like this: Colors.yellow.displayString

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I've edited the answer to demonstrate it.

Comment: how to get an enum object by value? Is it working here!

Comment: i think yellow.value does not work here. Enum can be removed and value may be implemented with @property as a workaround. Then it is not enum anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another approach, that is the code from: https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields

```py
import enum
import inspect

class ColorEnumMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        DisplayStrings = attrs.get('DisplayStrings')

        if DisplayStrings is not None and inspect.isclass(DisplayStrings):
            del attrs['DisplayStrings']
            if hasattr(attrs, '_member_names'):
                attrs._member_names.remove('DisplayStrings')

        obj = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        for m in obj:
            m.display_string = getattr(DisplayStrings, m.name, None)

        return obj

class Color(enum.Enum, metaclass=ColorEnumMeta):
    yellow = 1
    green = 2

    class DisplayStrings:
        yellow = 'Yellow'
        green = 'Green'

print(Color.yellow.display_string)  # 'Yellow'
```

or something that is based on this code, but a bit shorter:

```py
import enum

class ColorEnumMeta(enum.EnumMeta):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        obj = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        obj._value2member_map_ = {}
        for m in obj:
            value, display_string = m.value
            m._value_ = value
            m.display_string = display_string
            obj._value2member_map_[value] = m

        return obj

class Color(enum.Enum, metaclass=ColorEnumMeta):
    yellow = 1, 'Yellow'
    green = 2, 'Green'

print(Color.yellow.display_string)  # 'Yellow'
```

Answer (score -7):

You should normally never include literals like this in your code. The content should come from a file or database. But you can see how to build it up

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Color = namedtuple("color", "YELLOW,GREEN")(
        namedtuple("yellow", "value,display_string")(1, "yellow"),
        namedtuple("green", "value,display_string")(2, "green"))
>>> Color.YELLOW.display_string
'yellow'
```

This also works for older Pythons that don't support enum