# Create an object of the same class within the class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object

I want to have an object of a class within a class, because I need to pass it to a method, similarly to the example below. I would like the example below to print out 1, or fooObj.fooNum, but I keep getting a `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`.

```
class bar:
    def fooDef(self, fooObj):
        print fooObj.fooNum

class foo:
    fooNum = 1
    b = bar()
    f = foo()
    b.fooDef(f)
```

Comment: Why are you placing that code inside the `foo` class definition at all?

Comment: It should work if you reference `foo` from `foo.__init__()`, but not as a Class variable. I think.

Comment: This appears to be invalid class design: you have class-level code in `foo` that tries to create an object of its own class (without an initialization), pass the object to an *instance* method of `bar`, and then access a `foo` class attribute through the object.

Comment: @user2357112 In reality, this is for a much larger piece of code, one in which I must pass `self` or an instantiation of the class I am in.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Could you please clarify? I didn't quite understand what you meant, does this mean that I have to make a `def __init__(self)` within the foo class, before I declare an object?

Comment: @DhruvJain ignore me - it would create recursion. You probably need to rethink your design

Comment: Related: [Create static instances of a class inside said class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2546608/2823755)

Answer (score 1):

Please, can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

The error you see is normal, because the code immediately below `class foo` will be executed during the definition of `foo` and therefore the class is not defined yet.

If I understand well you want to define some method `foobar` of the class `foo`, which will use a `foo` instance. The correct procedure would then be

```
class foo:
    def foobar(self,):
        f = foo()
        ...
```

Again, with more details about what you are trying to do it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I want to create an instantiation of class A, and then pass it on to a method for class b, while I am in class A.

Comment: @DhruvJain: Why do you want to do it "while I am in class A"? It sounds like you have some deep misunderstanding of what it means to execute code directly within the body of a class statement, but it's hard to tell what that misunderstanding might be.

Comment: Ok, then my answer does apply, just replace `...` with `b = bar()` ; `b.fooDef()`, The solution of @Maurice-Meyer works  too and probably closer to your needs. The difference is that `__init__` is simply called at the instanciation of `foo` directly (so only once).

Answer (score 1):

Although it's unclear what you are asking, but the following changes do what you want to have.
But the code uses the instance of `foo()` not the class:

```
class bar:
    def fooDef(self, fooObj):
        print fooObj.fooNum

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fooNum = 1
        b = bar()
        f = self
        b.fooDef(f)

f = foo()
```

Prints:

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this is exactly what I wanted to do!